# Techniques/Tricks for Hiding/Abstracting SQL in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

According to http://www.toadworld.com/Portals/0/stevenf/Say%20Goodbye%20to%20Hard-Coding.pdf the author talks about hiding cursors/SQL in PL/SQL, but I couldn't find how it's done. Can someone enlighten with any simple approach on how it's done?. Thanks.

Comment: If you read the essay over again, you'll see that perhaps you've misinterpreted the word "hiding" to mean something like encrypting, whereas the author means something closer to  encapsulation (loosely defined). For example, rather than using constants throughout a module, use it once in its SPOD, and thereafter "expose" it via a function. In that manner, the constant definition can be changed without all of the programs that employ it having to be recompiled.  P.S. The author quotes Wikipedia on "hard-coding". Wikipedia is  wrong (duh) -- "hard-coded" was in use long before 1990.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steven Feuerstein is in favour of encapsulating all SQL inside PL/SQL functions, so instead of a developer writing:

```
select ename
into v_ename
from emp
where empno = v_empno;
```

they would write:

```
v_ename := emp_pkg.get_ename (v_empno);
```

The SQL is "hidden" inside the definition of the emp_pkg.get_name function.

I don't see where he specifically mentions hiding cursors in that presentation though?

Some people think Mr Feuerstein takes this approach too far - for example [Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:672724700346558185) (and myself).

Comment: Thanks for the link!. Interesting discussion there!

Answer (score 3):

My position regarding writing SQL inside PL/SQL is easily misunderstood, mostly because of he way I write about it!

PL/SQL is, in my mind, the BEST place to put SQL statements. The question is *where* to put the SQL. Here are the guiding principles I follow:

1. Write as much of your requirements in pure SQL. I am definitely *not* advocating that you break up a join into two function calls or something ridiculous like that. I am all for Tom Kyte's mantra: "Do it in SQL. If you can't do it in SQL, do it in PL/SQL. If you can't do it in PL/SQL, do it in Java." (or whatever)
2. Avoid repetition of just about everything.

If you don't think magic values should be repeated/exposed, why would you ever be supportive of exposing an SQL statement? If you need to get a row of data in this program, you (or others on your team) are likely to need it again. So put it in a function and call the function.

But this step comes *after* principle #1, not before it. You certainly don't compromise performance.

Once you've done this kind of hiding, though, you can take advantage of features like the function result cache much more easily, for just one example of how this hiding of SQL can benefit you and your apps.

Hopefully this clears things up a bit.

SF

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting discussion.  First, I'll say that I agree with *most* of what Steve Feuerstein says in that powerpoint.  I do think that eliminating repetition is a good goal, and for each API I try to (for example):

```
define constants in a single place(spec)   
use types/subtypes (even in a sep package) over varchar2(xxx)  
use utility functions (autonomous trans function for logs)   
define custom exception handling routines in sep package
```

Basically, things I will use over and over in this (or even other) apis.

However, I do NOT believe that the goal is to break everything down into tiniest little pieces and stick into ("hide" behind) functions.  If you do that, you are forcing yourself to ignore the real power of SQL and the Oracle engine itself.  You force Oracle to break up every problem into a bunch of little pieces you define, and then say "ok Oracle, instead of one join written in pure SQL, here's 10 function calls I need you to make and then combine/sort/etc to give me the same result"...Later..."why is this thing so damn slow?" (but at least the code looks pretty).

SF's answer to the slow question seems to be more features coming out lately (like function result cache).  I've been at this long enough to tell you these will help, but still can't hold a candle to properly written/tuned SQL.

Personally I don't see what is so evil about having actual SQL inside PL/SQL.  To me, building a pl/sql api is all about *actions*, what I want the user of the api to be able to *do*.  Each of these functions will most likely have SQL specific to that function (or action).  *Get the api right* rather than worry about breaking out all SQL into a bunch of function calls.  I can tell you, if the prettiest code in the world doesn't perform or scale (another issue with all these function calls), then it will eventually go bye bye anyway.

My 2 cents.